# XAMPP 1.6.4 and xdebug with NetBeans 8.2

Tags: php, apache, xampp, xdebug, php-5.2

How do I configure xdebug for `php 5.2.9` on XAMPP 1.6.4 with NetBeans 8.2 ?

```
;zend_extension_ts="C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
;xdebug.remote_enable=true
;xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
;xdebug.remote_port=9000
;xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
;xdebug.profiler_enable=1
;xdebug.profiler_output_dir="C:\xampp\tmp"
```

I tried uncommenting above lines and commenting `Zend` config lines. I also checked the port number on NetBeans Debugging option.

Comment: Show us xdebug section run in browser echo phpinfo(); More details

Comment: PHP 5.2 was discontinued almost 7 years ago, you should stop using it already.

Comment: I am not getting xdebug section in phpinfo();